# Пеерепесать jquery => vanila js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify

начал изучать vue js  и столкнулся с проблемой. вот такой воот просто скрипт я использовал  для анимированого отступа на jquery

```
jQuery('#main-page-offer .tabs li.tabs-title').click(function() {
  let itemScroll = jQuery('#main-page-offer .tab-scroll').outerHeight();

  if (jQuery(window).width() > 480) {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: itemScroll}, 500);
  }

});
```

Коммьюнити, подскажите,как сделать тоже самое на  vue?
очень хочу освоить фреймворк и native js!

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: `vanilla JS` - это сленг... ознанчает просто JavaScript, без дополнительных библиотек))

Answer (score 0):

Вот реализациия для vue js, возможно когда-то кому-то пригодится )

```
  v-tab(to="#tab-3" :ripple="false" @click="tabOffset()")


  methods: {
  tabOffset: function(){
  let element = document.getElementById('targetElement').offsetHeight;
  let headerOffset = 100;
  let offsetPosition = element + headerOffset;
  console.log(element);
  window.scrollTo({
    top: offsetPosition,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
},
```